# Jinja2 nested varibles

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Below are my jinja2 template file and the variables used to populate it. However I want to include a new section only if `aditional_keys = true`. Is this possible?

My variable

```yaml
  - { name: 'container1', version: '1.0.0.0', port: '', registry_path: 'container1', replicas: '1', namespace: 'general', aditional_keys: 'false'}  
  - { name: 'container2', version: '3.6.14.1', port: '8080', registry_path: 'container2', replicas: '1', namespace: 'general', aditional_keys: 'true'}
```

My template

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ item.name }}
    environment: {{ location }}_{{ env }}
  name: {{ item.name }}
  namespace: "{{ item.namespace }}"
spec:
  replicas: {{ item.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ item.name }}
      environment: {{ location }}_{{ env }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ item.name }}
        environment: {{ location }}_{{ env }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: {{ item.name }}      
        image: registry.com/{{ item.registry_path }}:{{ item.version }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: {{ item.name }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ item.port }}
          protocol: TCP
```

I tried adding this but I am obviously not calling the variable correctly

```
        {% if item.additional_keys == true %}
        env:
        - name: PRIVATE_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: id_{{ item.name }}_rsa
              name: id-{{ item.name }}-rsa-priv
              optional: false
        - name: PUBLIC_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: id_{{ item.name }}.pub
              name: id-{{ item.name }}-rsa-pub
              optional: false
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, [literal compare to boolean values](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/default_rules.html#literal-compare) is one of the ansible-lint rules you might want to follow.

Now there are 2 real issues in your above example.

1. You have a typo in your variable definition (`aditional_keys`) while you spelled it correctly in your template (`ad`**d**`itional_keys`)
2. Your variable is specified as a string (`'false'`) while you expect a boolean (`false`). Meanwhile, it often happens in ansible that correct boolean values can be turned into strings upon parsing (e.g. extra_vars on the command line). To overcome this, the good practice is to systematically transform the value to a boolean with the `bool` filter when you don't totally trust the source.

Once your fix the variable name and boolean definition in your var file as `additional_keys: false`, the following conditional in your template will make sure you don't get into that trouble again:

```
{% if item.additional_keys | bool %}
```